# jquery: reset css when new item is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, fade

I'm modifying [this script](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/03/16/expanding-image-menu/) to have the overlay fade out completely when clicked. The problem is if the css is changed to `display:none` I can't get it to return to `display:block`.

Here is the bit in question (original)

```
if(dir)
$ei_image.animate({opacity:0}, 1000);
else
$ei_image.css({opacity:0.5});
```

and what I am attempting (in various ways) but doesn't work

```
if(dir)
    $ei_image.fadeOut(500); 
else
    $ei_image.fadein(500);
```

Any ideas how I can get the div layer back when a new one is clicked?

EDIT **
I attempted to make a working jsfiddle for this, but even though all the code is there it isn't working. I can't figure out why. But at least the whole shebang is there for anyone who needs to put this bit in context.

I also tried this, which worked when fading out perfectly, but wouldn't turn the layer back on when navigating to a new column

```
if(dir)
    $ei_image.animate({opacity:0}, 1000 , function () {
        $(this).css({display:'none'}); 
    })
else
    $ei_image.css({display:'block'} , function () {
        $(this).animate({opacity:0.5}); 
    })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BZzRT/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/fastasleep/srLVs/

Line 104 in the js:

```
$menuItemsPreview.stop()
.animate({opacity:0.5}, 1500);
```

Changed to:

```
.fadeTo(500,.5);
```

Line 119:

```
if(dir)
$ei_image.hide().fadeIn(500);
```

Changed to:

```
$ei_image.fadeOut(1000);
```

At line 119, the overlay div does a fadeOut which takes it from from .5 opacity to 0 then goes display:hidden. The part at 104 resets the closed divs, which can't animate just opacity if the div is hidden, so you have to do a fadeTo which unhides the div, then animates to .5 opacity to match the other closed divs.

Also changed your  text to #fff so you could see it on the black bg. :)

Answer (score 0):

`fadeOut(500);` means hide the element that's why you elements are hidden .

try doing

```
if(dir)
    $ei_image.hide().fadeIn(500); 
else
    $ei_image.fadeOut(500);
```

Comment: that works, only after it fades out, it re-appears immediately... similar to having a light fade up then turn right off again.

Comment: looking at the CSS, what this does is turn the opacity to 0 then back up to .5 right away.

Comment: what you need than ??

Comment: i added a js fiddle so you could get a better idea of the code in it's entirety. for some reason it isn't working at all, but at least there's a better reference. it's supposed to open a column, then fade the overlaying layer to 0 (this i can actually do, but you still can't click anything below it, so the layer needs to actually be hidden), then when a new column is clicked it will re-appear at `opacity:.05`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the 0 to a 1 in the original .animate call.

```
if(dir)
$ei_image.animate({opacity:1}, 1000) ;
else
$ei_image.css({opacity:0.5});
```

Also, in your fiddle include jQuery in the drop down on the left and hit run.

I forked [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/corey/cCcLh/)

Is that what you were going for?

Comment: it should be the opposite, so instead of turning black, the overlay layer would disappear completely. what' i'm trying to accomplish is having each area be product information, so when that area is open, the information is readable, highlightable, hyperlinkable, etc